# Analysing a system of pulleys?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, string

[image]

I'm quite unsure on how to solve these questions.

For part (b), my approach was that the tension in the lower cable would have to be greater than or equal to $2m$ for both the masses to be lifted.

Using Newton's second law on the lower pulley, and assuming the pulleys to be massless, the tension in the upper cable is twice the tension in the lower cable.

Hence, the tension in the upper cable would have to be greater than $4m$ for the masses to be lifted, and so, M would have to be more than $4m$.

However, it is stated in the question that we expect $M \geq 8m$ as our answer.

Similarly, for part (c), if M = 4m, then the tension in the upper cable is $4mg$. Again, from Newton's second law, the tension in the lower cable is half this, $2mg$. And therefore, the vertical acceleration of mass A is given by:
$$2mg - mg = ma$$
In other words, $a = g$

However, the expected answer is $a = \frac{g}{2}$.

So in both cases, I have a factor of two error, so I'm clearly missing something. But I can't quite figure out what.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When the mass $M$ is moving with $a$, the lower pulley is in an accelerate frame. And the $2m$ will be falling in the non-inertial frame, with an acceleration $a'$. The condition $a > a'$ is necessary to ensure both $m$ and $2m$ are lifting. Otherwise, only the $m$ is lifting, $2m$ would stay still on the ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as mass B is partially supported by the surface, then the acceleration of mass A is twice that of M.  If the surface is not a factor, then the acceleration of M puts A and B into an accelerated frame, in which has a relative acceleration of a'.